# iTermを開くと、trace trapというものが表示される

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm

ふとiTermを開くと以下の様な文字が毎回表示されるのですが、これはなんですか？また、これを表示しない方法はありますか？

```
Last login: Wed Jan 14 22:19:05 on ttys003
[3]    19998 trace trap
user@macbook ~ $
```

Comment: この辺なのか？ http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21892/what-does-trace-trap-mean-when-reported-by-zsh

Comment: デフォルトのターミナルでは表示されません

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dotfilesとして[skwp/dotfiles](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles)を使用していてそれの中のmacvimが問題でした。

解決策:

```
brew uninstall macvim
brew remove macvim
brew cleanup
brew install macvim --custom-icons --override-system-vim --with-lua --with-luajit
```